# How many iterations of Taylor series for n correct decimal digits

Tags: taylor-expansion, estimation

I'm using Taylor series to estimate trigonometric functions. So I need to know exactly how many iterations of Taylor series (say for sine) are needed for n decimal digits precision?
(I'm writing a calculator program)
Thanks in advance

Comment: That depends on the function. Look into the [error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder).

Comment: Can you explain a bit? Particularly for sine function. (Simple please, I'm a first year student at university studying computer science)

Comment: I don't know how to give you a simple answer, to be honest. Hopefully someone better versed at this can find a way to explain it to you.

Comment: It also very dependent on the computing environment. Although $\sin(x)$ has an alternating Taylor series which is theroretically convergent for all real $x$, you will actually have **numerical** convergence only for small absolute values, for larger $x$ there **must** be cancellation, eg. for $x=42$ the largest term is about $10^{17}$, but $|\sin(x)|\le 1$! Therefore you will not get **any** correct digit with IEEE double!

Comment: @gammatester, What's best algorithm for estimating sine?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean with _estimate_. If you ask to _numerically_ compute $\sin(x)$, you should use the fact that $\sin(x+2n\pi) = \sin(x)$ to reduce the argument to $|x| \le \pi$, and sum the series until there is no change in the sum, i.e. you stop if the next term is less than $\epsilon$ times the current sum. This avoids large terms (the largest is about 5.2), but its better to use the symmetries to reduce the argument further to $|x| \le \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @gammatester That's a good idea. But checking the sum for changes every time, is more time consuming!

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends heavily on the distance between the point where you are taking the Taylor series (presumably at$~0$) and the value$~x$ for which you want to compute $\sin x$. The larger $|x|$, the worse the performance of the Taylor series, and the more terms are needed for a reasonable approximation. You may of course use the periodicity of the sine function to limit $|x|$ (supposing $x$ is real) before invoking your approximation.

Comment: So there is no formula for number of iteration needed knowing x and the desired precision?

Comment: You can work out a formula for the number of iterations needed given the coefficients of the Taylor series itself, the value of $|x|$, and the desired precision. In the practical range of application, evaluated terms of the Taylor series tend to $0$ at least as fast as a geometric progression, which means that the error is proportional to the first term not taken into account. If the geometric progression converges rapidly (ratio much less than$~1$), the size of that first omitted term itself is a fair estimate.